# Only plotting specified variables with plot.mids in R

Tags: r, r-mice

I have a mids object I got from running the mice algorithm in R. I'm trying to use plot.mids to assess convergence. I want to be able to plot convergence diagnostics for two specified variables. Here's an example:

```
library(mice)
nhanes1 <- nhanes
nhanes1[2,"age"] <- NA
mi1 <- mice(nhanes1,m=3,maxit=8,seed=2)
plot(mi1)
```

Here, only the plot for variable chl is displayed, although you can hit the back arrow to see the others, I'd like to just display chl and bmi together, in the same plot for a report. I tried specifying variables through the y=formula, but don't think I understand how to use that.

```
plot(mi1, chl~bmi)
```

That seemed to try to plot the means of chl against that of bmi (I think), which isn't what I'm after.

Comment: `plot(mi1, y=c("chl","bmi"), layout=c(2,2))`